# extracting unicode string with preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match-all

I'm trying to extract string using the following code:

```
$item = 'id="firstname" l="Prénom" n="firstname" t="text" v=""';
preg_match_all('#(?:l|label|lbl)\s*=\s*"([\x{00C0}\x{00C1}\x{00C2}\x{00C3}\x{00C4}\x{00C5}\x{00C6}\x{00C7}\x{00C8}\x{00C9}\x{00CA}\x{00CB}\x{00CC}\x{00CD}\x{00CE}\x{00CF}\x{00D0}\x{00D1}\x{00D2}\x{00D3}\x{00D4}\x{00D5}\x{00D6}\x{00D7}\x{00D8}\x{00D9}\x{00DA}\x{00DB}\x{00DC}\x{00DD}\x{00E0}\x{00E1}\x{00E2}\x{00E3}\x{00E4}\x{00E5}\x{00E6}\x{00E7}\x{00E8}\x{00E9}\x{00EA}\x{00EB}\x{00EC}\x{00ED}\x{00EE}\x{00EF}\x{00F0}\x{00F1}\x{00F2}\x{00F3}\x{00F4}\x{00F5}\x{00F6}\x{00F9}\x{00FA}\x{00FB}\x{00FC}\x{00FD}\x{00FF}\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"#is', $item, $m);
```

It works fine when using a non-unicode string like "firstname" but returns an empty value when **$item** contains a string like **"Prénom"**

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `u` to the list of modificators: `isu`.

Comment: because I only want numbers and letters (including french characters like é) so doing "([^"]+?)" could enable some characters like # @ and so on

Comment: Then simply add `u` to the list of modificators: `isu`. And maybe shorten the list of codes to `\x{00C0}-\x{00FF}`. In your example you've missed `00FE`

Comment: You're right, all it needed was to add the `u` modifier.  It would probably be best if you change your answer accordingly, for posterity.  As for the missing value, there are actually five of them `[\u{00DE}\u{00DF}\u{00E8}\u{00E9}\u00FE]` - and I'm pretty sure it was deliberate.